# Angular 2 routing resource not found

Tags: c#, typescript, visual-studio-2015, angular

I am using VS 2015 RC, working on a WebAPI project and when I try to use the routing in Angular 2 I get the following errors:

> Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 404 (Not Found) localhost:14580/angular2/router
>
> Potentially unhandled rejection [3] Error loading "angular2/router" at localhost:14580/angular2/router
> Error loading "angular2/router" from "Components/main/main" at localhost:14580/Components/main/main.js
> Not Found: localhost:14580/angular2/router (WARNING: non-Error used)

The view is the basic import of the main.ts component. The component code is as follows:

```
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/typings/angular2/angular2.d.ts" />
/// <reference path="../../Scripts/typings/_custom/ng2.d.ts" />

import {Router, RouteConfig, RouterLink, RouterOutlet} from 'angular2/router';
import {Component, View, bootstrap} from 'angular2/angular2';
import {Login} from '../login/login';
import {status, json} from 'Scripts/utils/fetch'


// Annotation section
@Component({
    selector: 'my-app'
})
@View({
        templateUrl: 'Views/main/main.html',
        directives: [RouterLink, RouterOutlet]
})
@RouteConfig([
{ path: '/login', as: 'login', component: Login }
])
// Component controller
export class Main {
    //router: Router;
    name: string;
constructor(router: Router) {
    //this.router = router;
    this.name = 'Routing';

   router.config([{ path: '/login', as: 'login', component: Login }]);
}

login(event, email, password) {
    event.preventDefault();

    window.fetch('/api/Account/Login', {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            email, password
        })
    })
        .then(status)
        .then(json)
        .then((response) => {
    alert(response);
        //    this.router.parent.navigate('/home');
    })
        .catch((error) => {
        alert(error.message);
        console.log(error.message);
    });
}

}
bootstrap(
    Main
);
```

Comment: You need to setup your web server so that `angular2/router` points to the js file

Comment: I don't think that's the problem, because the webserver finds `angular2/angular2` and `angular2/router` is in the same file as a module

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you bring in the latest definitelyTyped typings for Angular 2 it may be easier to get it working.
Here is a working example:

http://www.syntaxsuccess.com/viewarticle/routing-in-angular-2.0

Comment: Thanks.

The problem was not including router.dev.js from angular2. After that I had to disable MapRouter from IIS so I decided to drop Angular 2 definitely.

Answer (score 17):

You need to include `router.dev.js` on your html in the same way you included `angular2.dev.js`. So simply add this line to your `index.html`'s head:

```
<script src="../node_modules/angular2/bundles/router.dev.js"></script>
```

PS. I know you already solved this, but the answer was not clear and I took a while to realize what was wrong with my app.